# Laravel payment integration page goes blank

Tags: php, laravel-5

Code below

```
public function PayCCAvenue(Request $request)
{
    $parameters = [
        'tid' => '1233221223322',
        'order_id' => '1232212',
        'amount' => '1200.00',
        'firstname'=>'test',
        'email'=>'email@fffm.com',
        'phone'=>'7736190194',
        'productinfo'=>'sfszgvfsg'

    ];
    // gateway = CCAvenue 
    $order = Payment::gateway('CCAvenue')->prepare($parameters);
    //dd(Payment::process($order));
    return Payment::process($order);
}
```

After return Payment::process($order); page goes blank.  dd(Payment::process($order)); giving result.
tried different laravel packages. same issue

Comment: See [WSOD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death) and [How do i get PHP errors to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: try giving read write permissions to storage. in my experience laravel does doe a dd but not the fancy exception screen it has if the read write permissions are messed up

Comment: @mrQubeMaster laravel  exception screen working perfectly for other exceptios i checked by creating a division by zero exception.
     $a=1/0;
     return Payment::process($order);
also given 777 permison for storage. still blank screen.

Comment: @Xatenev:  laravel debugging on .again added error reporting on.
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
in php.ini 
display_errors = On;
but no error log related to this issue found.

Comment: I think problem is in routing because  I give a route redirection before executing the code(**return redirect()->route('bookingafterPayment')**) . the route not redirected.  and it doesn't show any error. but when i remove the bookingafterPayment  route in web.php it shows route missing error. ;

Answer (score 0):

**Old Code**

```
   public function payment(Request $request)
   {
       if ($request->payment_method == 1) {

          $this->paypalPAyment($request);

       } else if($request->payment_method == 1){

          $this->PayCCAvenue($request);

       }

    }


    public function PayCCAvenue(Request $request)
    {
        $parameters = [
            'tid' => '1233221223322',
            'order_id' => '1232212',
            'amount' => '1200.00',
            'firstname'=>'test',
            'email'=>'email@fffm.com',
            'phone'=>'7736190194',
            'productinfo'=>'sfszgvfsg'

        ];
        // gateway = CCAvenue 
        $order = Payment::gateway('CCAvenue')->prepare($parameters);
        //dd(Payment::process($order));
        return Payment::process($order);
    }
```

**Working code**

```
  public function payment(Request $request)
       {
           if ($request->payment_method == 1) {

              $this->paypalPAyment($request);

           } else if($request->payment_method == 1){

                  $parameters = [
                    'tid' => '1233221223322',
                    'order_id' => '1232212',
                    'amount' => '1200.00',
                    'firstname'=>'test',
                    'email'=>'email@fffm.com',
                    'phone'=>'7736190194',
                    'productinfo'=>'sfszgvfsg'

            ];
            // gateway = CCAvenue 
            $order = Payment::gateway('CCAvenue')->prepare($parameters);
            //dd(Payment::process($order));
            return Payment::process($order);

           }

        }
```

> No idea why laravel page redirection was not worked when the code was
>   in 
>       separate function.